# Some layouts don't draw when the keyboard goes down

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm working an app that draws objects on `SurfaceView` under some parameters, defined by the user. I created the layout for the app, which involves an header, footer, input (where user enters parameters to draw) and a custom `SurfaceView`.

Here's the layout that simplified:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Custom SurfaceView Layout -->

    <org.firengine.myapp.CustomPreview
        android:id="@+id/container_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- Header Layout: This is basically a Toolbar, with having a top padding of status bar height (see Note). -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorTint"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">...</FrameLayout>

    <!-- Footer Layout - This is just a container, with having a bottom padding of navigation bar height (see Note). -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_footer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorTint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">...</FrameLayout>

    <!-- Input Layout - This is a empty container that shows views dynamically. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container_header" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The input layout generate dynamic views, based on parameters.

Suppose I create a `EditText` inside input layout, so that the keyboard appears if you interact with that.

This is before the keyboard shows up.

[image: Before Keyboard Shows Up.]

This is when the keyboard is showing. Notice that the app layout is panned and the header layout got invisible.

[image: Keyboard Is Showing.]

The problem occurs when the keyboard goes down. The header layout, which is invisible earlier, stays invisible all the time (until the user interacts with the app).

[image: After Keyboard Shows Up.]

I turned on GPU overdraw to check the problem (also setting `SurfaceView` background color to white), and here is the result.

Before:

[image: Before with GPU overdraw.]

After:

[image: After with GPU overdraw.]

Also, here's my custom `SurfaceView` class (I think that the custom `SurfaceView` is blocking the UI thread to draw the layouts that disappeared).

```
public class CustomPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }
    };

    private Renderer renderer;

    private boolean visible;
    private boolean canLoadData;

    private HashMap<String, String> data;

    public CustomPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        visible = false;
        canLoadData = false;
        renderer= new Renderer(context);
        data = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        visible = true;
        refreshHandler(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        renderer.updateDimensions(width, height);
        canLoadData = true;
        renderer.updateData(data);
        refreshHandler(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        renderer.clearData();
        visible = false;
        canLoadData = false;
        refreshHandler(0);
    }

    public void setVisibility(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        refreshHandler(0);
    }

    private void draw() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                renderer.draw(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        refreshHandler(60000);
    }

    public void saveData(String key, String value) {
        data.put(key, value);
        if (canLoadData) {
            renderer.updateData(data);
        }
        refreshHandler(0);
    }

    private void refreshHandler(long delay) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        if (visible) {
            if (delay > 0) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
            } else {
                handler.post(runnable);
            }
        }
    }

    public String loadData(String key) {
        return data.get(key);
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? If so, can someone explain what it is?

I'm glad if someone helps me out.
Thank you.

**Note:** Heres some extra information about the layout.

1. Footer layout was originally had a `AdView`, which is not included in the layout.
2. `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flags was added to the activity and because of that, paddings were set in respective layouts to avoid overlapping.
3. And, header layout has 2 Toolbar views, which one of them are seen in the images above.

Comment: post your whole xml code of above screen

Comment: Although I haven't solved my problem, I am awarded the bounty to the person who answered the question because I didn't provided the necessary information that caused the problem. This question is now closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following in the Manifest

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"**

```
<activity 
    android:name=".app.main.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `AdjustNothing` will solve the problem, but it will hide the `EditText` if the soft keyboard is shown. (Also, I have tried `AdjustResize` and It doesn't work. (probably because I'm using a `SurfaceView`.))

Comment: Also, Sorry for late response because I was away from programming on these past days.